# $K\subseteq X$ is compact iff every net in $K$ has an accumulation point in $K$

Tags: general-topology, alternative-proof, nets

Is it possible to prove the statement

> Let $X$ be a topological space. Then $K\subseteq X$ is compact iff every net in $K$ has an accumulation point in $K$.

based on the following theorem, which I have proven,

> Let $X$ be a topological space. Then $X$ is compact iff every net in $X$ has an accumulation point.

as a corollary?

Answer (score 4):

This should just follow from the fact that K is a compact subset of X if and only if K is a compact space under the subspace topology.

Comment: If this is the case, how can you be sure that the accumulation point in $X\supseteq K$ lies in $K$?

Comment: You can rephrase your theorem more precisely as  "X is compact iff every net in X has an accumulation point **in X**". Now if you say that K is compact and you take a net in K, then the accumulation point you get from the theorem lies in K already.

Comment: @Mr.MathDoctor You consider $K$ in the subspace topology as a new space in its own right. So "the universe" is then only $K$. There is no other place the accumulation point can be... Compactness is an *intrinsic* property.